# Spannable style isn't applying

Tags: android, spannable

So, i'm having a message which contains text and `SpannableStringBuilder` which is initialized like this :

```
final SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder(message.getMessage());
```

And by default, i'm setting font to `BOLD` :

```
builder.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, messageText.length(), 0);
```

But my message text will be changed, example :

Your question : {question}
Your answer : {answer}

{question} and {answer} are objects that will be replaced with text, replacing is happening like this:

```
final  TextObject question = objects.getQuestion();
spannable = new SpannableString(question.getText());
spannable.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.NORMAL), 0, spannable.length(), 0);
builder.replace(start, end, spannable);
```

Text is replacing just fine, but NORMAL font type isn't applying to it, so i have all text BOLD, but i need this parts to be normal

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You have to add that Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE as a last parameter

```
spannable.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.NORMAL), 0, spannable.length(), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
```

and if you want some part in bold and some not you have to be specific which part. The second and the third parameter of setSpan method is responsible for that

Comment: It's not working, but thanks for a suggestion, i'll workaround with flags

Comment: try to set NORMAL by default and set only bold parts in places where you need

Comment: I can't because i have no clue which parts needs to be bold, i just know which don't

Comment: f.e. you have a string which is 30 chars long and part which has to be NORMAL Typeface is from 5-10 you have to set two Bold spans one from 0-5 second from 11-30